# PHPStormのBladeのインデント設定が反映されない

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

LaravelをPHPStormを利用して開発しています。

PHPのインデントを4
Bladeファイルのインデントを2（デフォルトは4）
に設定しましたが、
Reformat Codeしてもコードのリフォーマットは走りますが、インデントが4から2に変わりません。

設定方法が悪いのでしょうか？
同じような設定していてうまく行っている方、アドバイスをいただけると助かります。
よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

しくみがよくわかってないのですが、
Code Style -> Enable Editor Config support
のチェックボックスにデフォルトでチェックが入ってたのですが、
試しに外してみたところリフォーマットが効くようになりました。

チェックをはずすと別の所で副作用があるかもしれませんが、
とりあえずこの対応で行こうと思います。